# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=SOMEURL] unknown field ''

Tags: solr, nutch

Hi I am getting this exception and I've exhausted all the possible settings that I could think of.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=SOMEURL] unknown field ''
```

The problem is **field ''** - the quotation marks are empty so I don't know what causes the problem.

Does anybody had the same problem? I will help me a lot.

Some informations:

- Nutch version 2.1
- Solr version 1.5
- Hbase as a data storage
  -Tomcat6 for Solr running

In code have just this:

```
nutchDocument.add("my_key",stringValue);
```

I have checked Solr's schema.xml, Nutch's schema.xml and also Nutch solr-mapping.xml (I am sure in the right directories) in each is "my_key" written in the right way.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to be blind. I found where was the problem. For someone who will have the similar problem here is the reason:

In my **solrindex-mapping.xml** I had this:

```
<field dest="video_og_title" source="video_og_title" />
<field dest="video_og_type" source="video_og_type"/>
<field dest="video_og_image" source="video_og_image" />
<field name="video_og_url" source="video_og_url"/>
<field name="video_og_description" source="video_og_description" />
<field name="video_og_video" source="video_og_video" />
```

I didn't see the field has attribute `name` and not `dest` so Solr represent the `dest` attribute, which it uses for mapping like empty field ' '.